# Errors after MIUI ROM flashing with TWRP

Tags: twrp, miui, mediatek, miui-10, redmi-note-4

I'm trying to flash Xiaomi EU stable version of MIUI 10 on my Redmi Note 4 MTK.

- TWRP: `3.0.2`
- ROM: `Xiaomi EU MIUI 10 (HMNote4_V10.2.1.0)`
- Gapps: `arm64-6.0-nano`

After first flash with full wipe, it has stuck in Setup Wizard at SIM selection with `Unfortunately, Setup Wizard has stopped` error.

Java error message:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: The method 'void android.telephony.SubscriptionManager.setDefaultDataSubld(int)' was expected to be of type virtual but instead was found to be of type direct (declaration of 'com.google.android.setupwizard.carrier.SimSetupActivity$SetSimDataFragment' appears in /system/priv-app/SetupWizard/SetupWizard.apk)
at com.google.android.setupwizard.carrier.SimSetupActivity$SetSimDataFragment.apply(SimSetupActivity.java:166)
at com.google.android.setupwizard.carrier.SimSetupActivity$SimSetupFragment.applySelection(SimSetupActivity.java:326)
at com.google.android.setupwizard.carrier.SimSetupActivity$SetSimDataFragment.applySelection(SimSetupActivity.java)
at com.google.android.setupwizard.carrier.SimSetupActivity.start(SimSetupActivity.java:93)
at com.google.android.setupwizard.BaseActivity.onNextPressed(BaseActivity.java:378)
at com.google.android.setupwizard.BaseActivity.onNavigateNext(BaseActivity.java:660)
at com.android.setupwizardlib
```

Then I re-flashed it without wipes. And another error emerged - `Unfortunately, Settings has stopped`

Java error message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.settings/com.android.settings.wifi.WifiSetupActivity}:
java.lang.lllegalStateException: You need to use a miui theme (or descendant) with this activity.
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(Activity Thread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(Activity Thread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygotelnit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygotelnit.java)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygotelnit.main(Zygotelnit.java)
Caused by: java.lang.lllegalStateException: You need to use a miui theme (or descendant) with this activity.
at com. miui.internal.app.ActivityDelegate.installSubDecor(SourceFile)
at com.miui.internal.app.ActivityDelegate.onCreate(SourceFile)
at miui.app.Activity.onCreate(SourceFile)
at com.android.settings.kg.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java)
at com.android.settings.wifi.WifiSetupActivity.onCreate(WifiSetupActivity.java)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java)
... 10 more
```

What do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Do not install any Gapps over Xiaomi EU Stable ROMs. The ROM already has Gapps and installing another Gapps can cause conflict. Flashing the ROM without Gapps solved the problem for me.